# Не получается правильно написать блок «if», с дополнительными формами

Tags: delphi

У меня в БД много таблиц, в каждой таблице (подключен свой *DataSet*) есть одинаковые поля, например: '*USER_ID*' и '*DEPARTMENT_ID*', а также есть поле '*ARCHIVE*', которое есть **не во всех таблицах**.
В программе, несколько модулей, и не все *DataSet* находятся на одной форме.
При каждом редактировании записи в любом из *DataSet*, я постоянно должен заполнять '*USER_ID*' и '*DEPARTMENT_ID*', '*ARCHIVE*'.
Для этого я создал отдельно процедуру в главном модуле, которую вызываю при каждом Post любого DataSet:

```
procedure TFMain.SET_IDENTIFICATOR(ADataSet: TIBDataSet);
begin
  if (ADataSet <> ibdsContractPays)
    or ((FDeviceNC <> nil)
        and (ADataSet <> FDeviceNC.ibdsNC)) then
    ADataSet.FieldByName('ARCHIVE').AsInteger := 1;

  ADataSet.FieldByName('USER_ID').AsInteger := Pu_UserIDEntry;
  ADataSet.FieldByName('DEPARTMENT_ID').AsInteger := Pu_DepartmentID_Entry;
end;
```

Все было хорошо, пока не попался один из *DataSet* (*ibdsNC*), который находится не на главной форме, а на второстепенной *FDeviceNC*, и в таблице которого нет поля '*ARCHIVE*'.
У меня не получается правильно написать блок «*if*».
Получается он то срабатывает, то нет (при каждом НЕ срабатывании конечно пишет «

> Field 'ARCHIVE' not found.

»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure TFMain.SET_IDENTIFICATOR(ADataSet: TIBDataSet);
var 
  fldArchive: TField;
begin
  fldArchive := ADataSet.FindField('ARCHIVE');
  if fldArchive <> nil then
    fldArchive.AsInteger := 1;

  ADataSet.FieldByName('USER_ID').AsInteger := Pu_UserIDEntry;
  ADataSet.FieldByName('DEPARTMENT_ID').AsInteger := Pu_DepartmentID_Entry;
end;
```

*Совет дня: для размещения компонентов `TDataSet` используйте `TDataModule`.*

Comment: Мне всеже понравился способ (с двух строк) "if ADataSet.FindField('ARCHIVE') <> nil then
  ADataSet.FieldByName('ARCHIVE').AsInteger := 1;"

Comment: @Konstantin78 Не экономьте строки :) - в откомпилированной программе их нет. В этих двух строках поле ищется два раза.

Comment: А "TDataModule" - это имеется в виду  "File -> New -> Other -> Delphi Files -> DataModule"?

Comment: **Спасибо за ответ**. Что касается "TDataModule" - это правильно для старых версий delphi, но я использую Delphi 10.2, там по правой кнопке мышки на форме, есть опция "Hide non-visual  component" - скрывает все НЕ визуальные компоненты, мне так проще, не знаю правда насколько это правильно

Answer (score 0):

```
if fldArchive <> nil then
   `begin`
   fldArchive.AsInteger := 1;
 ADataSet.FieldByName('USER_ID').AsInteger := Pu_UserIDEntry;
 ADataSet.FieldByName('DEPARTMENT_ID').AsInteger := Pu_DepartmentID_Entry;
   `end;`
```

Comment: добавьте begin и end; тогда блок условия будет работать всегда.